# Construct array using JSON from Bean object

Tags: java, javascript, json, jstl

Hello all I have a bean that has 3 getters.  In the JSP I use JSTL to iterate over the bean to populate a table.  I have saome javascript I need to do the same thing to construct an array.  Here it is hardcoded, but how can I contruct it by itearing over a bean?

Bean: This is how I do it in the JSP using JSTL

```
<c:forEach var="bean" items="${beans}">
     ${bean.month}       
     </c:forEach>
```

How Can I do the same thing here:

Javascript:

```
"categories": [{
    "category": [{
       "label": "Oct"
    }, {
        "label": "Nov"
    }, {
        "label": "Dec"
    }, {
       "label": "Jan"
    }, {
        "label": "Feb"
    }, {
        "label": "Mar"
    }, {
        "label": "Apr"
    }, {
        "label": "May"
    }, {
        "label": "Jun"
    }, {
        "label": "Jul"
    }, {
        "label": "Aug"
    }, {
        "label": "Sep"
    }]     
    }]
```

Trying to do something like this in javascript

```
 <c:forEach var="bean" items="${beans}">
     [{
       "label": " ${bean.month}"
    },         
     </c:forEach>
```

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript or JSON, so you'll just get a syntax error.

Comment: Are you trying to construct an array, or iterate over an existing array?

Comment: Your question is really unclear, are you trying to generate JSON in a JSP or work with an object in Javascript?

Comment: The part I have labeled javascript is what im trying to iterate over and create.  Its currently hardcoded.  But I have a bean object that has a getter and I want to use that to populate all the months

Comment: I basically want to creat that exact section I have labeled javascript, but with a for loop

Comment: In that case, since it seems you want to generate JSON in a JSP, I'd recommend taking a look at the [json-taglib](http://json-taglib.sourceforge.net/). It's a set of custom JSP tags for generating JSON data. Not the only set of custom tags to do that, but it is the one I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not well experienced in JSTL. This is a guess based on the experience I have in PHP.

```
var array = [
<c:forEach var="bean" items="${beans}" varStatus="beanStatus">
    {
        "label": "${bean.month}"
    }
    <c:if test="${!beanStatus.last}">  // put comma after all item, but last one
         ,
    </c:if>          
 </c:forEach>
];
```

or

```
var array = [];
<c:forEach var="bean" items="${beans}">
    array.push({
        "label": "${bean.month}"
    });         
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var category = [], // new Array
    i,
    newCategory;

for (i = 0; i < beans.length; i += 1) {
    newCategory = {}; // new object
    newCategory.label = beans[i].month;
    category.push(newCategory);
}
```

Comment: hmmmmmmmmmmmm...trying this also